# Stack Exchange sites (e.g. english.stackexchange.com) talk about Stack Overflow on the “offline for maintenance” page

Tags: bug, status-completed, maintenance

When a Stack Exchange site is “offline for maintenance”, it displays various Stack Overflow-specific graphics, most notably its logo.

[image: StackOverflow logo]

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have been fixed

Graduated sites ([English](http://english.stackexchange.com) and [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) in this case):

[image]

[image]

Beta sites:

[image]

(still uses Sketchy, though)

Stack overflow:

[image]